# Universal property of tensor product of $R$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A_1,...,A_{n+1}$ be $R$-algebras.

Let $A_1\otimes_R\cdots\otimes_R A_{n+1}$ be equipped with the natural $R$-algebra structure.

Let $N$ be an $R$-algebra.

Let $\phi:A_1\times\cdots \times A_{n+1}\rightarrow N$ be a middle linear map such that $\phi(a_1b_1,...,a_{n+1}b_{n+1})=\phi(a_1,...,a_{n+1})\phi(b_1,...,b_{n+1})$

Then, there exists a unique $(R,R)$-bimodule & $R$-algebra homomorphism $\Phi:A_1\otimes_R ...\otimes_R A_{n+1}\rightarrow N$ such that $\Phi(a_1\otimes...\otimes a_{n+1})=\phi(a_1,...,a_{n+1})$.

Is there a name for maps such as $\phi$? $R$-multialgebra?

Comment: @user26857 Another term is "balanced". That is multiadditive and  $\phi(mr,n)=\phi(m,rn)$, but need not be $\phi(mr,n)=r\phi(m,n)$

Comment: Hungerford uses the term *"middle linear"* where as Dummit & Foote used both the terms *"middle linear"* and *"$R$-balanced*". For commutative algebras, the term *"bilinear"* is usually used.

Comment: But isn't then $\phi$ automatically $R$-multilinear? Because we then have for example $\phi(ra_1,a_2,...,a_{n+1})=\Phi((ra_1)\otimes a_2\otimes...\otimes a_{n+1})=r\Phi(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes...\otimes a_{n+1})=r\phi(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n+1})$